# Null safety in Kotlin for MutableMap with MutableList

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I am trying to run this example

```
fun main() {
    val mlist: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf<String>()
    val mapp: MutableMap<Int, MutableList<String>> = mutableMapOf(1 to mlist)
    println(mapp)
    mapp[1].add("a") // Correct is mapp[1]?.add("a")
    println(mapp)
}
```

at [Online Kotlin Compiler](https://play.kotlinlang.org/).

The compiler is complaining about  `Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type MutableList<String>?`.

Although I have defined `MutableList<String>` why the compiler says something about `MutableList<String>?`.

What does the compiler understand more than me?! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in mutableMap, value can be added or removed, the compiler has no guarantee that the value is still present or has been changed before accessing the value in mutableMap types

Comment: Yes! The `remove` function!

Answer (score 5):

The compiler does not say: '... something about MutableList<String>?.' What the compiler is saying, is, that *mapp[1]* could return *null*.

```
 mapp[1]       // this is the short notation for:
 mapp.get(1)
```

Both return in your case a *MutableList<String>?*. Why is this return value nullable? It could be that *mapp* does not contain an element with the key *1*. And then *get(1)* will return *null.*

If you are absolutely sure, that the element with key *1* is present in *mapp* use *!!*, if not use *?* and *add("a")* will not be executed.

Comment: You can also use `getValue()` instead of `[]!!` to better illustrate intent and get a better error message if the assertion is wrong.